# Facebook moderated comments don't work with href attribute

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments, xfbml

I have a page with facebook comments on it, and here is the problem:

When I put the HREF attribute I can't manage/moderate the comments, and when I don't put HREF attribute, it gives me the following error/message:

> **Warning**: this comments plugin is operating in compatibility mode, but has no posts yet. Consider specifying an explicit 'href' as suggested in the comments plugin documentation to take advantage of all plugin features.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, I had forgot about the og and fb tags on header. If you having the same issue try to put

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content=""/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content="[put current url here]" />
```

on the  tag.

Now you can use

```
<fb:comments href="[put current url here]" num_posts="2" width="620"></fb:comments>
```

Here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object you can see what facebook thinks about your url